# BigQuery Running Sum

Tags: sql, count, distinct, google-bigquery, cumulative-sum

I have a dataset in BigQuery that records donations made to individuals leading up to an event. Here is the schema

- first_name:STRING --- (This is the donors name)
- payment_date:TIMESTAMP --- (date of the donation)
- amount:STRING --- (donation amount)
- donated_to_individual:STRING --- (participant collecting the donation)
- location:string --- (location of event the individual will participating in)
- year_of_run:STRING --- (year of the event)

I am trying to create a table from which I can graph the running count along payment_date of individuals for each location who have received a sum total of $50 or more of donations.

My best attempt, below, left me with a table that could count the number of people who raised $50 or more ONLY if they received a donation THAT day:

```
SELECT
donated_to_id_b
,payment_date
,amount
,running_total
,IF(running_total>=50,'$50','NOPE') as reached_50_dollars

FROM
(SELECT
donated_to_individual as donated_to_id_b
,payment_date as payment_date
,amount
,sum(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY donated_to_id_b ORDER BY payment_date ASC, first_name) as running_total

FROM [robotic-charmer-726:bl_test_data.running_count_over_50_then_150]
WHERE year_of_run='2014')
```

I'm afraid I'm taking the completely wrong approach... so any help would be MUCH appreciated!

I have created a public dummy data set that can be found here: bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/robotic-charmer-726:bl_test_data.running_count_over_50_then_150

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the overall approach is sound - analytic functions (i.e. OVER clause) is the right mechanism in SQL to deal with running sum. The only thing that bothered me a bit in your SQL was that you renamed donated_to_indivudual column inside SELECT, and used the renamed alias inside PARTITION BY. While OVER clause is evaluated last, it would be better for readability (and portability) not to rely on aliases being carried over.